# Norm in double dual

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $X''$ be its double dual.

Is it true that $\|x\|_X=\|x\|_{X''}$?

What I know is $\|x\|_{X''}=\sup_{\|l\|=1}|xl|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clearly, the evaluation at $x \in X$ is a bounded linear form on $X^*$ : that's the natural injection $\iota$ from $X$ to its bidual $X^{**}$ defined by  $\iota(x)(y) = y(x)$. and for some $z \in X$ : $$\|\iota(z)\|_{X^{**}} = \max_{y \in X^*} \frac{|y(z)|}{\|y\|_{X^*}} = \max_{y \in X^*} \frac{|y(z)|}{\max_{x \in X, \|x\|_{X}=1} |y(x)|} = \max_{y \in X^*} \max_{x \in X,\|x\|_{X}=1}\frac{|y(z)|}{|y(x)|}$$ and show that the maximiser $x \in X, \|x\|_{X}=1$ is in fact $x = \frac{z}{\|z\|_{X}}$ hence :

$$\|\iota(z)\|_{X^{**}} = \max_{y \in X^*} \frac{|y(z)|}{|y(z/\|z\|_{X})|} = \|z\|_{X}$$

Comment: 1. why is this the max? 2. Can we just move the max out from the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $$||x||_{X} =||\kappa x||_{X''}$$ where $\kappa :X\to X''$ is the canonical embedding defined by $(\kappa x ) (u) =u(x)$ for all $u\in X' .$