# Where does this equality of the $L^p$-norm come from?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm reading a proof, where it is shown that a function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ is a function in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$. The author shows that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \varphi f \; \mathrm dx \leq C \Vert \varphi \Vert_{L^q(\mathbb R^n)}$ for each $\varphi \in C_c(\mathbb R^n)$. He now states that 
$$
\Vert f \Vert_{L^p} = \sup_{\varphi \in C_c(\mathbb R^n) \atop \Vert \varphi \Vert_{L^q} \leq 1} \int_{\mathbb R^n} \varphi f \; \mathrm dx < \infty \; ,$$
where $q$ is chosen to satisfy $\frac 1 p + \frac 1 q = 1$.

I don't understand why this equality holds. I can only assume that it has something to do with the density $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ and maybe the Hölder inequality? Can someone explain this to me, or show me where to look this up?

Comment: it is the Banach space norm in the dual of the dual . do you know that if $y \in X^*$ then $\displaystyle \|y\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1, x \in X} |x(y)|$ ? here we do the same in the bi-dual $(L^p)^{**}$ which is the dual of $(L^p)^* \simeq L^q$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces and yes for proving that $L^q$ is the dual of $L^p, 1/p + 1/q = 1$ you'll need Holder's inequality.

Comment: and yes, the constraint $\varphi \in C_c$ can be added by noting that $C_c$ is dense in $L^q$. finally, what you have to prove is that $\displaystyle \| \iota( f)\|_{X^{**}} = \|f\|_X$ (with $\iota$ the so-called natural injection in the bi-dual) see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724280/norm-in-double-dual

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation.